# sendmail Laravel not sending email

Tags: php, laravel, sendmail

I wrote the following code to send an email to a specified email adres using a Laravel Controller method:

```
public function sendEmail(Request $request){
        $question = $request->get('question');
        $phone = $request->get('phone');

        $from_email = $request->get('email');
        $from_name = $request->get('name');

        $to_email = 'XXX';
        $to_name = 'XXX';

        $data = array('name'=>"Sam Jose", "body" => $question . "\n" . $phone);

        Mail::send(array(), $data, function($message) use ($to_name, $to_email, $from_email, $from_name) {
            $message->to($to_email, $to_name)
                ->subject('Vraag | XXX');
            $message->from($from_email, $from_name);
        });
    }
```

Besides that I added the follwing to my .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=XXX
MAIL_PASSWORD=XXX
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

This code does send a mail to the specified address if I run it on my localhost, if I run it on my subdomain it doesn't send the email without giving any error message.

Comment: please try `MAIL_PORT=587`

Answer (score 0):

At top of your controller

```
 use Mail;
```

use this code in controller function to send mail.The mail.welcome is the mail body which you are sending..

```
$data=array('body'=>$message,'name'=>'XXXXX');
Mail::send('mail.welcome',$data,function ($message)use ($email,$subject)
{
$message->to($email)->from('XXXXX@gmail.com', 'XXXX')->subject($subject);
}); 
if(count(Mail::failures()) > 0){
return redirect()->route('mail.view')->with('error','Error in sending mail');
}
else {
return redirect()->route('mail.view')->with('response','Mail Send Successfully');
}
```

If you are using gmail to send mail.Change your .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score -1):

probably you don't have `sendmail` installed on your hosting. I would recommend using [MailGun](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail). It is built in with Laravel and free to use. It should work seamlessly wether on localhost or live server.

Comment: It's still not able to send the email, still a blank page even while using MailGun

Comment: it is a blank page because your sendMail does not return any view. Make sure you add your email to a sandbox email in MailGun. Otherwise, MailGun wont send email unless you have your own domain setup on Mailgun. The other option is using MailTrap for testing.

Comment: Author asked how to use sendmail. Recommending alternative service couldn't fix his existing problem with sendmail.